# VBA Excel, Не применяются настройки Excel после внесения изменений в реестр

Tags: excel, vba, реестр

Есть макрос в файле Excel, проверяющий доступ к объектной модели проекта VBA (Настройки Excel) находящийся в модуле проекта - Module_vbomCheck.
Есть макрос, включающий этот доступ, вызываемый из модуля выше, тоже находящийся в отдельном модуле проекта - Module_vbomChange.
Если выполнять код непосредственно из модуля, все работает - доступ включается, но при открытии файла (Sub Workbook_Open() запускается из "ЭтойКниги"), настройки не применяются. В чем может быть дело?

**Module_vbomCheck**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Check_VBOM()
    Dim oVBProj As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oVBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    If Not oVBProj Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response, MyString
        Msg = "Доступ к объектной модели VBA запрещен, хотите разрешить? Excel закроется для применения настроек."
        Style = vbYesNo + vbInformation + vbDefaultButton1
        Title = "Проверка доступа к объектной модели VBA"
        Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
        If Response = vbYes Then
            Call Module_vbomChange.Change_VBOM
            Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Excel.Application.Quit
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Module_vbomChange**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Change_VBOM()
    Dim objExcelApp As Object, objShell As Object, ExlVersion As String, vbomLevel As Long
 
    Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExlVersion = objExcelApp.Version: objExcelApp.Quit
 
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & ExlVersion & "\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM", 1, "REG_DWORD"
    objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & ExlVersion & "\Excel\Security\VBAWarnings", 1, "REG_DWORD"
    Set objExcelApp = Nothing: Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Догадка: Книга еще не открыта ---> проект тоже не открыт ---> объектная модель недоступна

Comment: @vikttur, возможно, не подумал об этом. А как можно это сделать? Куда поместить Workbook_Open()?

Comment: *Workbook_Open* - в модуле книги и никуда перемещать не нужно. Попробуйте поставить вызов *Sub Check_VBOM* в конце процедуры. Может быть, поможет задержка *Application.Wait*

Comment: @vikttur, в конце процедуры не могу, у меня в процессе выполнения кода динамически создается форма. Она просто не создастся без этой злосчастной галочки )

Comment: Создаем проблемы, чтобы героически их преодолевать? ) Нельзя ли форму создать вручную, не кодом и книгу открывать с уже готовой формой?

Comment: @vikttur, ну конечно ))) Но хотелось бы все оставить как есть, то есть динамически.